# Display small top-down map in corner while in Street View using Google Maps API and JS

Tags: javascript, google-maps, blazor

I'm using Maps.GoogleAPIs to display a map on my webpage, I'd like to enable the lil' corner map view while in street view. This is probably more of an issue of having no idea how to word a Google search to find the solution.

Looking through the JS I have controlling the map, the nearest to where I might add options to control this is where I have:

```
_map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(lt, ln),
    zoom: 16,
});
```

Below shows an example of the corner map I'd like to enable.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

What you could do is just create two `divs`. One for the panorama, and one for the map.

I found a side by side sample on the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/streetview-simple), and it has `<div id="pano">` and `<div id="map">`.

I just modified the sample on the documentation by putting the `<div id="map">` inside the `<div id="pano>` like this:

```
<div id="pano">
    <div id="map"></div>
</div>
```

Then modified the CSS of the `#map` by setting it like this:

```
#map {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

the z-index enables it to appear on top of the street view and the other settings are pretty much what makes it stay on the bottom left side of the streetview. Then I just added the `mapTypeControl: false,` and `zoomControl: true` to somehow replicate the photo that you showed.

Ref: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls

Here's a code snippet that shows the implementation you wanted:

```js
function initialize() {
  const fenway = { lat: 42.345573, lng: -71.098326 };
  const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: fenway,
    zoom: 14,
        mapTypeControl: false,
    zoomControl: true
  });
  const panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
    document.getElementById("pano"),
    {
      position: fenway,
      pov: {
        heading: 34,
        pitch: 10,
      },
    }
  );

  map.setStreetView(panorama);
}

window.initialize = initialize;
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#pano {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#map {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Street View with map inside</title>
    <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style.css" />
    <script type="module" src="./index.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <div id="pano">
        <div id="map"></div>
    </div>

    <!-- 
     The `defer` attribute causes the callback to execute after the full HTML
     document has been parsed. For non-blocking uses, avoiding race conditions,
     and consistent behavior across browsers, consider loading using Promises
     with https://www.npmjs.com/package/@googlemaps/js-api-loader.
    -->
    <script
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initialize&v=weekly"
      defer
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here's also a proof of concept [fiddle](https://jsbin.com/qerarus/1/edit?html,css,js,output). Note: Just use your own API key and make sure that it is restricted and not shared in public sites.

Hope this helps!